# MOSFET driver circuit for wireless charger improvements

Tags: mosfet-driver, modulation, wireless-charging

I'm designing a circuit for power wireless charge.
The final application is a remote controller which needs to be charged and programmed with no cables.

The circuit i designed, charge the battery of the controller and transfer information over the TX and RX coil, TX uses a FSK modulation to send data and check controller presence, RX uses a ASK modulation to response back, so I'm able to update controller firmware from master (TX circuit) or send commands to controller MCU while charging for changing charging current, oscillating frequency etc.

I just asking if MOSFET LC-tank drive circuit can be improved in efficiency, reducing losses generated by inductive load.
I know that Royer oscillator could be a better solution, but I need the modulation for communicate over coils (maybe a Royer oscillator which can be controlled somehow).

Here's my circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6obPP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Can I improve the M1 MOSFET stage somehow?